# unit tests and object-inheritance

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a question concerning "unit tests" and object-inheritance. For example:

I have a class A which extends class B. Let's assume the only difference of the two classes is the add method . In class B this add method is slightly extended. Now I want to write a unit test for the add function of class B but because of the parent::add call I have a dependency to the parent class A. In this case I can't mock the add method of the parent class so the resulting test will be a integration test but if I want it to be a unit test? I don't want the the test for method add in class B fails because of the parent method in class A. In this case only the unit-test of the parent method should fail.

```
class B exends A
{
    public function add($item)
    {
        parent::add($item);
        //do some additional stuff  
    }
    ....
}

class A
{
    protected $items = [];
    public function add($item)
    {
        $this->items[] = $item;
    }
    ....
}
```

Surely I could use object-aggregation and pass my parent object to the child contructor and therefore I would be able to mock the parent method add, but is this the best approach? I would rarely use object-inheritance anymore.

```
class B
{
    protected $a;

    public function __contruct(A $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function add($item)
    {
        $this->a->add($item);
        //do some additional stuff  
    }
    ....
}

class A
{
    protected $items = [];
    public function add($item)
    {
        $this->items[] = $item;
    }
    ....
}
```

I would be very grateful for your opinions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask yourself, what kind of inheritance do you want to achieve? If B *is a kind of* A, then you're wanting *interface inheritance*. If B shares a lot of code with A, then you're wanting *implementation inheritance*. Sometimes you want both.

Interface inheritance classifies semantic meaning into a strict hierarchy, with that meaning organized from generalized to specialized. Think [taxonomy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/taxonomy). The interface (method signatures) represent the behaviors: both the set of messages to which the class *responds*, as well as the set of messages that the class *sends*. When inheriting from a class, you implicitly accept responsibility for *all* messages the superclass sends on your behalf, not just the messages that it can receive. For this reason, the coupling between super- and sub-class is tight and each must strictly substitute for the other (see [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).

Implementation inheritance encapsulates the mechanics of data representation and behavior (properties and methods) into a convenient package for reuse and enhancement by sub-classes. By definition, a sub-class inherits the interface of the parent even if it only wants the implementation.

That last part is crucial. Read it again: **Sub-classes inherit the interface even if they only want the implementation.**

Does B strictly require the interface of A? Can B [substitute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) for A, in all cases matching co-variance and contra-varience?

- If the answer is *yes*, then you have true sub-typing. Congratulations. Now you must test the same behaviors twice, because in B you are responsible for maintaining the behaviors of A: for every thing A can do, B must be able to do.
- If the answer is *no*, then you merely need to share the implementation, test that the implementation works, then test that B and A separately dispatch into the implementation.

In practical terms, I avoid `extends`. When I want implementation inheritance, I use `trait` to define `static` behaviors <sup>†</sup> in one place, then `use` to incorporate it where needed. When I want interface inheritance, I define many narrow `interface` then combine with `implements` in all the concrete types, possibly using `trait` to leverage behavior.

For your example, I'd do this:

```
trait Container {
    public function add($item) { $this->items[] = $item; }
    public function getItems() { return $this->items; }
    private $items = [];
}

interface Containable { public function add($item); }

class A implements Containable { use Container; }

class B implements Containable {
    use Container { Container::add as c_add; }
    public function add($item) {
        $this->c_add($item);
        $this->mutate($item);
    }
    public function mutate($item) { /* custom stuff */ }
}
```

`Container::add` and `B::mutate` would have unit tests, while `B::add` would have an integration test.

In summary, *favor composition over inheritance* because [`extends` is evil](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073649/core-java/why-extends-is-evil.html). Read the ThoughtWorks primer [Composition vs. Inheritance: How To Choose](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose) to gain a deeper understanding of the design trade-offs.

---

<sup>†</sup> "static behaviors", you ask? Yes. Low-coupling is a goal and this goes for traits. As much as possible, a trait should reference only variables it defines. The *safest* way to enforce that is with static methods that take all their input as formal arguments. The *easiest* way is to define member variables in the trait. (But, please, avoid having traits use member variables that are not clearly defined in the trait -- otherwise, that's blind coupling!) The problem, I find, with trait member variables is that when mixing in multiple traits you increase the chance of collision. This is, admittedly, small, but it is a practical consider for library authors.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, I really appreciate your effort! But I am not sure if I want to use static trait's here. I expanded my example above and the add method now adds some new $item to the $items property of A and I don't think a static trait would be very useful here. I am also not a very big fan of static methods because they are not mockable. I also found this useful article about [traits](https://eliasvo.wordpress.com/2015/06/07/php-traits-if-they-werent-evil-theyd-be-funny/). I'm not implying that the usage of extends is the better approach.

Comment: Rather than focus on the `static` as an implementation, focus on the purpose: to keep the trait decoupled from the consumer. Having a trait that declares and manages its own internal state is perfectly fine. See my edit.

Comment: Thx! It's a very interesting approach. I will look further into this.